# script doesnt allow file name to show in input

Tags: javascript

Image input is allowing to upload images without displaying the name of the file. I want to be able to see the file name when I upload an image; how can I make this possible? Could it be something to do with my script?

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    console.log("Reading File.");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
      if (jQuery("#preview-gallery li").length == 3) {
        input.value = "";
        return false;
      }
      var $imgP = jQuery("<img>", {
        class: "uploaded-image icon",
        src: reader.result
      });
      var $item = jQuery("<li>", {
        class: "ui-widget-content ui-corner-all hidden"
      });
      $item.append($imgP).append("<a href='#' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>");
      $item.appendTo(jQuery("#preview-gallery")).show("slow");
      makeDrag($item);
      updatePreviewCount();
    });
    if (input.files[0]) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } else {
      console.log(" Reader: File Not found.");
    }
    input.value = "";
  }
}

function renderContent() {
  html2canvas(jQuery("#firstshirt"), {
    allowTaint: true,
    logging: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    jQuery("#previewImage").append(canvas);
    jQuery("#download").css("display", "inline");
    jQuery("#download").attr("href", jQuery("#previewImage")[0].children[0].toDataURL());
  });
}

function makeDrag(o) {
  o.draggable({
    helper: "original",
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 999
  });
}

function makeResize(o) {
  o.resizable();
}

function addImage($item, $pos) {
  console.log("  Fade Item Out");
  $item.fadeOut();
  var $img = $item.find("img");
  $img.css("width", "80px").css("height", "80px");
  $item.remove();
  updatePreviewCount();
  console.log("  Making new Wrap");
  var $drop = jQuery("<div>", {
    class: "dragbal deleteme",
    style: "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;"
  });
  $drop.append($img);
  console.log($drop);
  console.log("  Appending to #boxes");
  $drop.appendTo(jQuery("#boxes")).fadeIn();
  $drop.draggable({
    containment: "#boxes"
  });
  makeResize($drop.find("img"));
}

function updatePreviewCount() {
  var cnt = jQuery("#preview-gallery li").length;
  jQuery(".upPreview span").html(cnt + "/3");
}

jQuery(download).ready(function() {
  // Setup
  jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
  jQuery(".out-put-img").hide();
  jQuery('.smallimages').hide();

  makeDrag(jQuery("[id$='-gallery'] ul li"));

  jQuery("#boxes").droppable({
    accept: ".gallery > li",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Drop Pos:", ui.offset);
      addImage(ui.helper, ui.position);
    }
  });

  // Events
  jQuery("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    renderContent();
    jQuery("#download").removeClass("disabled");
  });

  jQuery("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled");
  });

  jQuery("#imajes45").change(function() {
    if (jQuery('#imajes45').val() == "new-upload") {
      jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").show();
      jQuery(".file-select").hide();
    } else {
      jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper").hide();
      jQuery(".file-select").show();
    }
  });

  jQuery(".file-select").change(function() {
    jQuery(".upPreview").hide();
    jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).val() + "-gallery").show();
  })

  jQuery(".upload-img").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });


});
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');

if (myform != undefined) {
  myform.onsubmit = function(e) { /* do some validation on event here */ };
}



$("#wrapper").hover(function() {
    $("#boxes").css("border-color", "red");
  },
  function() {
    $("#boxes").css("border-color", "transparent");
  });

$(document).ready(function() {


      $(".container").on("dblclick", ".deleteme", function() {
        console.log('clicked delete')
        $(this).remove();
      });
```

```css
<link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" /> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> <script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

```html
<select id="imajes45">
  <option value="">Choose upload</option>
  <option value="new-upload">Upload Images</option>
</select>
<div class="file-upload-wrapper" id="draggableHelper" style="display: none;">
  <div>
    <input type="file" class="upload-img" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="readURL(this);" /><span id='contactus_file1_errorloc' class='error'></span>
  </div>


  <div>
    <input type="file" class="upload-img2" name="file2" id="file2" onchange="readURL(this);" /><span id='contactus_file2_errorloc' class='error'></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="file" class="upload-img3" name="file4" id="file4" onchange="readURL(this);" /><span id='contactus_file4_errorloc' class='error'></span>
  </div>

  <div id="upload-preview" class="small upPreview">
    <span>0/3</span>
    <ul id="preview-gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the prevent default

```js
  jQuery("#btn-Preview-Image").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    renderContent();
    jQuery("#download").removeClass("disabled");
  });

  jQuery("#download").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return jQuery(this).hasClass("disabled");
  });
```

Comment: Your snippet has an error.

Comment: yes this happens when i separate that part of the code from the rest. if you like i can give you the website so you can take a look at a working code

Comment: @Zze here is my webpage https://torcdesign.com/prison/

Comment: It's not overly clear what you are asking, Where and when do you want to see the file name?

Comment: i want to see the file name as soon as i upload an image in the input   here         <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="readURL(this);" />

Comment: Prior to the upload, during or after?

Comment: during upload just like a normal upload how it shows the name of the file

Comment: An input gives you a FileList which is a array-like set of File objects.  File objects have a `name` property. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: if you remove the `onchange` event the name appears as default, so you must be overwritting something or maybe a `preventDefault()` is being called `onchange` .

Comment: yes but when i remove onchange the imqge is not displayed

Comment: yes a preventDefault is being called

Comment: Don't forget to @me so I get notified of your response... Does it work if you remove the preventDefault?